# Linux errors in loading and executing unix script file

Tags: linux, unix

In  this example I am trying to use my unix script to delete my world folder on server reload and cp the backup world into a new world folder that is being created. However, when this code runs on my network server it throws different errors. When I run it on my computer it runs perfectly fine. Some of these errors include "not found: start.sh" which is the file name and "cp: cannot create regular file 'world'$'\r''/region/r.-1.0.mca': No such file or directory". Another common error shown is "not found: start.sh: clear". The file does not always delete the world folder like it is supposed to. It has all permissions. I've also tried these commands without the ./

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;do java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -XX:UseSSE=4 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar start.jar;

clear
rm -rf ./world
mkdir ./world
cp -r ./GameWorldBACKUP/* world

done
```

Comment: `chmod u+x start.sh` may help. And running it as `./start.sh`, or even `bash start.sh`.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your actual problem.

Comment: "not found: start.sh: clear" You may have carriage returns in your script file, perhaps because you've been editing it on a Windows system. Run your script through the dos2unix program to clean it up.

Comment: @Evert It does because they are both causing each other to happen when those errors pop up the file doesn't work right but sometimes they don't pop up and it works fine. and I've tried running it as bash and chmod already.But Kenster's comment worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

""not found: start.sh: clear" You may have carriage returns in your script file, perhaps because you've been editing it on a Windows system. Run your script through the dos2unix program to clean it up." - Kenster

This method worked